# Redundant `let`s in list monadic code

Tags: haskell

There is a function with bunch of a redundant `let`s and `←`s inside a list monad.

```
example ∷ (Int, Int, Int, Int, Int)
example = head $ do
  let list1 = [0,1]
  e1 ← list1
  let list2 = φ list1 e1
  e2 ← list2
  let list3 = φ list2 e2
  e3 ← list3
  let list4 = φ list3 e3
  e4 ← list4
  let list5 = φ list4 e4
  e5 ← list5
  return (e1,e2,e3,e4,e5)
    where φ ∷ [Int] → Int → [Int]
```

So, all `list#` values are unusable. How can `example` could be rewritten with `>>=` or maybe with something else to get `(e1,e2,e3,e4,e5)` without any `let`s?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why this question was closed with such a reason, the code looks pretty real and it could be compiled

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hm, this could probably be done using `foldM` or similar, but that would require you to convert to and from lists. My first impulse would be to try to write the top-level of `example` using Applicative style:

```
import Control.Applicative

example = head $ (,,,,) <$> m <*> m <*> m <*> m <*> m
```

But that doesn't work directly here, as you want each `m` to know the `list#` of the last action.

One way to realize this without breaking up the above structure would be to have a `StateT` monad transformer take care of passing around the current `list#`:

```
import Control.Monad.State

example = head $ flip evalStateT [0,1] $
          (,,,,) <$> m <*> m <*> m <*> m <*> m
```

This allows us to write `m` as a list monad with state:

```
  where m :: StateT [Int] [] Int
        m = do list <- get
               e <- lift list
               put (phi list e)
               return e
```

Now admittedly, this is a bit advanced. It might be easier to try to restructure `phi` or use a `foldM` type solution.